# VB to C# conversion error (assign and if statements)

Tags: c#, vb.net, rpa, uipath

what is the proper way to convert

```
if((year mod 4=0 and year mod 100<>0) or (year mod 400=0), “Leap Year”, “Not a Leap Year”)
```

To C#

I was able to successfully convert the first part  `if ((year % 4 == 0 & year % 100 != 0) | (year % 400 == 0))` but when I add the messages, I get an error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @MindSwipe, that's not actually true. In VB, you have the short-circuiting Boolean operators `AndAlso` and `OrElse`, the non-short-circuiting Boolean operators `And` and `Or` and the bitwise operators `And` and `Or`. There are C# equivalents to all of those and, just as in VB, the non-short-circuiting Boolean operators and the bitwise operators are the same. That is to say that, in C#, you have the short-circuiting Boolean operators `&&` and `||`, the non-short-circuiting Boolean operators `&` and `|` and the bitwise operators `&` and `|`.

Comment: @MindSwipe, you probably have just never encountered the non-short-circuiting Boolean operators in C# because pretty much no one uses them, as pretty much no one should. The same is true in VB but, because of all the history of VB6 and before, where there were no short-circuiting operators, a lot of people use the wrong ones.

Comment: wow just learnt about non short circuiting operators!

Comment: @jmcilhinney interesting, I didn't know that. My VB knowledge starts and ends at 45 minutes of playing with MS Office Macros. I have however come in touch with the short circuiting vs non short circuiting operators in C#, they just slipped out of my mind as (like you said, and for good reason) pretty much no one uses them

Comment: Optimistic code, btw. The next time it actually it more useful than a simple mod 4 is 2100. Very few of us reading this will be alive then. I wonder if the code will be still running.

Comment: @Enigmativity good to see future proofing taken seriously

Comment: @MindSwipe Office macros are VBA, which only has the bitwise / non-short-circuiting operators.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The equivalent of that VB `If` operator is the C# [ternary operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) (`?:`), i.e.

```vb
If(x, y, z)
```

is equivalent to:

```cs
x ? y : z;
```

For the record, there's another `If` operator like this:

```vb
If(x, y)
```

which evaluates to `x` if `x` is not `null`, otherwise it evaluates to `y`. The C# equivalent is called the [null coalescing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator) (`??`):

```cs
x ?? y;
```

Answer (score 5):

The original VB code should have used the [DateTime.IsLeapYear(Int32) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.isleapyear), so that in C# it would become:

```
DateTime.IsLeapYear(year) ? "Leap Year" : "Not a Leap Year";
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer in compilable code is:

```
private string LeapYearResponse(int year)
{
    if ((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0))
        return "Leap Year";
    else
        return "Not a Leap Year";
}
```

Or more concisely:

```
private string LeapYearResponse(int year)
{
   return ((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0)) ? "Leap Year" : "Not a Leap Year";
}
```